# How to make dynamic paint work with rigid body interactions during animation playback

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation, displacement, dynamic-paint

[image: dynamic paint not responding to rigid bodies interaction simulation but works in object mode]

I'm trying to dynamically wave paint a passive, rigid body, wave-modified plane canvas with an active, rigid body, sphere brush via dynamic animation playback.

The dynamic painting works when changing the location of the brush, i.e., the sphere, in object mode, but fails when the dynamic, rigid body animation is played in real-time, as you can see in the gif. Blender allows for a single interaction at the beginning of the animation, but then the sphere just rolls on top of the canvas without displacing any of its geometry during the animation.

I want to upload my blend file but don't know how.

Perhaps a shrinkwrap-modified plane to the canvas will work.

The brush only works with "distance from center" as the source which is set well above any collision margins.

I've tried applying the wave modifier to the plane to no avail. I've tried pretty much all combinations of settings for the dynamic paint and rigid bodies, even adjusting the render fps, to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround that may be acceptable while sacrificing some dynamic behavior.

What I found out is that you can turn a rigid body simulation into a string of keyframes via a built-in function under the object menu in object mode called "rigid body" > "bake to keyframes".

I had realized that the dynamic paint seems to work only with a keyframed brush, but I wanted that authentic, physics feel to the simulation, thus the solution was to bake a rigid body simulation and then turn it into keyframes. Lastly, I removed the rigid body physics from the brush sphere, pressed play, et voila!

[image: rigid body dynamic paint working]

Hooray!

[image: the final result]